# Can I get a percentile in MS SQL Server Management Studio 17

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, percentile

I need to show the 50th percentile in SSMS I am using TSQL and the percentile_cont but it isn't recognised? Is there another way?

I am querying a table like this:

```
HerdID   Event
100      01/01/2009
100      08/01/2009
```

There are multiple HerdID and the events occur over multiple years and in one year there are multiple events for each HerdID. I am interested in the Week number that the events occur for each herd each year. After getting some help from here I got this query:

```
SELECT HerdID
      ,YEAR([Event]) As YearID
      ,DATEPART(wk,[Event]) As A
      ,MIN (DATEPART(wk,[Event])) OVER (PARTITION BY HerdID, YEAR([Event])) AS B
      ,MAX (DATEPART(wk,[Event])) OVER (PARTITION BY HerdID, YEAR([Event])) AS C
      ,COUNT([Event]) OVER (PARTITION BY HerdID, YEAR([Event])) AS D
      ,cast( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HerdID, YEAR([Event]) ORDER BY DATEPART(wk,[Event])) as dec(5,2))
        / cast (COUNT([Event]) OVER (PARTITION BY HerdID, YEAR([Event])) as dec(5,2)) AS E
```

And it gives me the table below.

```
HerdID  YearID  A   B   C   D   E   
000001  2009    6   6   53  3   0.333333
000001  2009    14  6   53  3   0.666666
000001  2009    53  6   53  3   1.000000
000002  2009    5   5   34  4   0.250000
000002  2009    16  5   34  4   0.500000
000002  2009    27  5   34  4   0.750000
000002  2009    34  5   34  4   1.000000
```

I think if I could get the 50th percentile of

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HerdID, YEAR([Event]) ORDER BY DATEPART(wk,[Event])) AS A
```

It would give me a table like this where A is the week number that 50%+ of the herd has been born

```
HerdID  YearID  A   B   C   D   E   
000001  2009    14  6   53  3   0.666666
000002  2009    16  5   34  4   0.500000
```

Many thanks

Comment: The version of SSMS you have has nothing to do with whether or not you can use `percentile_cont`, it's what version of SQL Server you have. What version of SQL Server are you using? The fact that `PERCENTILE_CONT` isn't recognised **implies** you're using an unsupported version of SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry- I'm a newbie and running before I can crawl. It seems to be MS SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU4) which looks like it should work with ```PERCENTILE_CONT``` but it didn't highlight as a function

Comment: What do you get from select @@version?

Comment: That doesn't mean it isn't. Try and if you get an error, post that.

Comment: I tried and I got an error so I have used it wrong. I need to get the median of ```ROW NUMBER ()``` rather than the median of a column in my table is this possible?